# ARKit Physics Objects Phasing through tracked planes

Tags: physics, collision, arkit, bitmask

I am currently trying to modify the plane tracking demo that apple provided to have little cube projectiles bounce off the tracking planes that the app creates.

I have added physics bodies to the respective projectile and wall, but for some reason the projectile continues to ignore the collisions and just phases through the wall. I have tried adding and removing the bit masks, but they don't seem to affect anything.

Here is what I am currently doing for my tracked planes:

```
init (anchor: ARPlaneAnchor, in sceneView: ARSCNView) {
        guard let meshGeometry = ARSCNPlaneGeometry(device: sceneView.device!) else {
            fatalError("CANNOT CREATE GEOMETRY")
        }

        meshGeometry.update(from: anchor.geometry)
        meshNode = SCNNode(geometry: meshGeometry)
        meshNode.name = "ENV."        
        super.init()

        self.setupMeshVisualStyle()
        let body = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)
        meshNode.physicsBody = body
        addChildNode(meshNode)
    }
```

Here is the bullet physics implementation

```
class func spawnBullet() -> SCNNode {
        // Omitted code (just setting size and stuff)

        let cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
        cubeNode.name = "BULLET"
        let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.dynamic, shape: nil)
        physicsBody.isAffectedByGravity = false
        physicsBody.damping = 0
        physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionCategory.bullet.rawValue
        physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionCategory.env.rawValue | CollisionCategory.player.rawValue
        physicsBody.continuousCollisionDetectionThreshold = 0.01;
        cubeNode.physicsBody = physicsBody
        return cubeNode
    }
```

I have created a separate SCNPlane object with the exact same physics body settings as the tracked plane settings. What's odd is that the bullets successfully collide off of the SCNPlane, but they continue to pass through the tracked planes with the exact same settings.